# Can't find InstallSchema in Cms/Wishlist module Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2.3

I am newbie for Magento 2 development. Sometime, I reference Magento Core module.
But still Magento 2.3, I can't find `Cms/Setup/InstallSchema.php`

Where I can find it?

Comment: In 2.3 almost all schema are created from db schema, check db_schema.xml in etc directory.

Comment: I got it. Do you have any document for db_schema.xml?